# How to add to set and increase counter in scala?

Tags: scala

I want to add an item to the set, if item doesn't exist in set already. If item is added, I want to increase the counter and return the count at the end.
What is the scala way of doing this?

Here is what I have so far.

```
var fruitSets: Set[String] = Set()

def addToSetAndSum(): Int = {
  var counter = 0
  val fruit: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "apples", "apples")
  for (f in fruit) {
    if (!fruitSets.contains(f)) {
      fruitSets += f
      count += 1
    }
  }
  counter
}
```

Comment: what is your expected return value? is it 3?

Comment: yes, 3 is the expected return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the set of items in `fruit` that aren't in `fruitSets` using `fruit.toSet -- fruitSets`, allowing you to rewrite your code as follows:

```
var fruitSets: Set[String] = Set()

def addToSetAndSum(): Int = {
    val fruit: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "apples", "apples")
    val newFruit = fruit.toSet -- fruitSets
    fruitSets ++= newFruit
    newFruit.size
```

Alternatively, just add the contents of `fruit` to `fruitsets` using `++=` and compare the sizes of fruitSets before and after:

```
def addToSetAndSum(): Int = {
    val fruit: List[String] = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "apples", "apples")
    val initialSize = fruitSets.size
    fruitSets ++= fruit
    fruitSets.size - initialSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a Set is the more appropriate Structure in this case, because you want to store the counter at the end.

My solution:

```
val fruits = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "apples", "apples")
val result = fruits.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```

the result is:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(oranges -> 1, pears -> 1, apples -> 3)
```

In this way you have a Map with fruits and the corresponding counter.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't like you to use any mutable collections or vars in your Scala code. So check this out, done simply using tail recursion.

```
object Test extends App{

  def addToSetAndSum(set: Set[String], items: List[String], count: Int): (Set[String], Int) = {
    items match {
      case Nil => (set,count)
      case x :: xs if(!set.contains(x)) => addToSetAndSum(set+x, xs, count+1)
      case x :: xs => (set, count)
    }
  }

  val set = Set.empty[String]
  val fruits = List("apples", "oranges", "pears", "apples", "apples")
  val result = addToSetAndSum(set,fruits,0)

  println(result._1, result._2)
}
```

You can even use case classes instead of tuples to increase code readability.

Answer (score 0):

One clean and Scalaish solution is below which it has a var(Not recommended) but to have some kind of persistence I will go with that this time.

```
case class Items[T](var items: Set[T]) {
  def addItemsToSet(item: T): Int = {
    if(!items(item)) items = items + item
    items.size
  }
}


defined class Items

scala> val i = new Items(Set.empty[Int])
i: Items[Int] = Items(Set())

scala> i.addItemsToSet(1)
res0: Int = 1

scala> i.addItemsToSet(2)
res1: Int = 2

scala> i.addItemsToSet(3)
res2: Int = 3

scala> i.addItemsToSet(3)
res3: Int = 3
```